# app store connect: can't upload build as role developer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I've been added to an apple developer team for developing an app. My apple ID is added to a specific app in the app store connect console with the following roles:

- developer
- marketing
- customer support

I am the only developer for the app, so I need permission to upload builds. When opening xcode, I can't change the Team in Signing & Capabilities to the team I've been added to. I only see my own team.

Do I need extra permissions, and how to fix this?

**Edit:** both apple developer accounts are individual accounts, not company accounts. Could this be the problem?

Comment: You cannot change the Team popup to a team you are not on. If you _are_ on the team in question you will see that team in the popup. So I would have to suggest you are not on that team.

Comment: Did you receive the invitation email? Maybe you failed to notice it. You have to receive it and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload the app as developer in individual account.You can do that only on enterprise account.